# Red5chat connection iterator fails

Tags: java, red5

Currently working on a flashchat that connects to red5.

The webapp used: http://www.freedevelopment.net/articles/free-red5chat.html

Users can connect, chat. But private messages and admin actions fail.

This is because of the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Values
cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator at
net.freedevelopment.chat.Application.kick(Application.java:302)
```

The code there states:

```
public void kick(String _id) {
    Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();
    //log.debug("kick called: "+_id);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
    IConnection conn = it.next();
    String id=conn.getClient().getId();
    if (!(_id.equals(id))) continue;
        if (conn instanceof IServiceCapableConnection) {
            ((IServiceCapableConnection) conn).invoke("IhaveBeenKicked", new Object[]{_id});
            log.info("kick "+_id);
        }   
    }
} // line 302
```

So I guess the iterator is not valid, but I have no clue to what this should be casted.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Something is wrong with line numbering. Could you please also show `net.freedevelopment.chat.Application.kick` method?

Comment: @Max edited with the kick method

Comment: Weird, checked the API and examples and everything seems to be ok. However your line numbering is still messed up. I'm guessing you forgot to deploy the new version or something like that.

Comment: Did a default install of red5 (latest from site), with the webapp of freedevelopment.
Does it mean it can't find a class?

Comment: Just did a complete fresh install of Red5 and the wepapp.
Same error again.

Comment: Sorry but I really have no idea. I never used Red5, just checked their api and examples fast and I can not see why you are getting such stupid error. getConnections does return Iterator<IConnection> (at least api and examples say so). So I am out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer responded that this is a known problem, should be fixed in the near future.